# Typescript: Extend prop interface of custom parent React.Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a abstract Row class in my Typescript/React app:

```
export interface IAbstractRowProps {
    assignedValueY: IValue;
    valueZId?: number;
    matrixStore?: MatrixStore;
}
export abstract class AbstractRow extends React.Component<IAbstractRowProps, {}> {
    // ...
```

A conrecte component inherits from that:

```
export default class DayRow extends AbstractRow {
    protected getCellItems(): ICellItem[] {
        // ...
    }
}
```

And then I want a second component to inherit from `DayRow`. But I also want to extend the props on this component. Something like this:

```
export interface IDayFinderRowProps extends IAbstractRowProps {
    anotherProp: boolean;
}

export default class DayFinderRow<IDayFinderRowProps, {}> extends DayRow {
    protected getCellItems(): ICellItem[] {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This syntax produces errors.
I this even possible to achieve or do I have to add all the props I might need to the `IAbstractRowProps` interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make `DayRow` and `AbstractRow` generic themselves so the generic type can flow to `React.Component`. For `DayRow` you can specify the default type, so you can instantiate it without specifying the generic parameter.

```
export abstract class AbstractRow<T extends IAbstractRowProps> extends React.Component<T, {}> {
}

export class DayRow<T extends IAbstractRowProps = IAbstractRowProps> extends AbstractRow<T> {

}
export class DayFinderRow extends DayRow<IDayFinderRowProps> {

}
```